# html and php code mixed in a php variable

Tags: php, variables

I have a php variable and I had to insert into it html code with another variable. ie:

```
myarray['foo'] = "<p><? echo $var; ?></p>"
```

but in this way it doesnt' work. How could escape it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
myarray['foo'] = "<p>$var</p>"
```

PHP handles all the parsing for you.

EDIT:

From your comment about the array, you could print the raw contents of the array (not very helpful for an app, but fine for debugging):

```
myarray['foo'] = "<p>".print_r($var, true)."</p>";
```

Comment: @davidethell it work even if the variable is a an array variable? like $array->var ?

Comment: @eng_mazzy, no it won't. It will try to cast $var to a string which will just show the text "Array" for an array. You would have to loop through the array to do something with each array or else use print_r. I edited the answer to show it.

Answer (score 1):

```
myarray['foo'] = "<p>" . $var . "</p>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do

```
my_array['foo'] = '<p>'.$var.'</p>';
```